# How much data(input) validation is needed in frontend app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, security, frontend

The beginning of everything came from the question I had while defining `react-router`'s match parameter type in typescript code.

The `matchParams` type was not auto-generated by **route path**, even the files defining the `matchParams` and **route path** were **different**.

```js
// app.tsx

const enum Path {
  Main = '/',
  Search = '/search',
  Project = '/project/:projectId',
}

export const App = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={Path.Search} component={SearchPage} />
      <Route path={Path.Project} component={ProjectPage} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

```js
// projectPage.tsx

type MatchParams = {
  projectId: string;
};

export type ProjectPageProps = RouteComponentProps<MatchParams>;
export const ProjectPage = (props: ProjectPageProps): ReactElement => {
  // now, typeof 'props.match.params.projectId' is "string"
  // but at actual runtime, it's not sure

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

So at first, I defined all properties in `matchParams` optional. However, considering how `react-router` works, I don't think this is intuitive because `props.match.params.projectId` is never undefined. If the `projectId` is not given, the `projectPage` will not be mounted.

Through googling, I learned that there are several libraries for data validation. Among them, I tried to apply `Ajv`. But where should it be applied?

I have another user-defined component, `searchBox`. And in that, there's `input` DOM object that has "string" type `value` property.

```js
// searchBox.tsx

export const SearchBox = (props: SearchBoxProps): ReactElement => {
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>('');

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    // I thought, it's clear that typeof 'event.currentTarget.value' is "string"
    // because typeof 'text' is "string"
    // But is it really so?
    setText(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <inpu
      id="test"
      value={text}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      onChange={handleChange}
      type="search"
    />
  );
};
```

When I opened the browser console and tried `document.getElementById("test").value = 12345`, the `value` of input seemed to be set to `12345`, type "number". But strangely, when I focused on the search input, the value returned to `text` from `12345`, and in this case, I was able to confirm that it worked as safely as intended. But I'm still not sure that's the case for every form input.

I hope there will be no program crash or pure exposure of errors to the console due to bad data at runtime. And I think maybe these are security vulnerabilities in my program. However, I am also worried that my efforts are meaningless because the client's source code is exposed anyway.

Verifying all user inputs (including URLs and forms) requires too much effort. And if I use `ajv`, the code structure will become too complicated for reasons such as module dependency in the process of data schema creation.

I understand that verification of all external data is **essential on the server-side**, but how much verification is required on the client-side?